# Jmeter/Selenium - How do I access specific endpoint

Tags: selenium, performance, testing, jmeter

I have a simple performance test flow in an application.

1. Login
2. Process1
3. Process2
4. Process3
5. Logout

I am using Jmeter/Selenium to do a performance testing. I am currently debugging an endpoint in Process3("/example/path"). The problem is that I have to run the entire automation for me to get to that endpoint in Process3. Is there a way to skip the processes and navigate to that specific endpoint(not headless)? For example:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("https://domain/path/path/endpoint");

//Authentication
implicitFind(pkg.By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
implicitFind(pkg.By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
implicitFind(pkg.By.id("login")).click();

//below code would be for debugging endpoint in UI
```

When I run WebDriver Sampler, it presents the login page, which I do not mind asking to login. But after I login, webapp does not go to endpoint and throws a NullPointerException. Would I need to add a Cookie Manager? If so, how would I go with doing this using a WebDriver Sampler. If no, is there another way to successfully achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the application doesn't properly redirect you to the "endpoint" after logging in - it's your application problem only, there is nothing you can do about it on JMeter or Selenium level.

It you want to run Process 3 only and skip Process 1 and Process 2 just temporarily disable them using "Disable" or "Toggle" context menu actions

[image]

As you can see the "greyed out" samplers are not executed.

[HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) relates only to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, https://www.selenium.dev/ is a browser automation framework and [browsers handle cookies automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)